# How to dynamically infer a the values of a generic array as a union in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, types, type-inference

Given the following declaration:

```js
declare function useStrings<T extends string[]>(
  arr: T,
  fn: (item: T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never) => void
): void;
```

I expect the `item` parameter in `fn` to be a union type of the values of `T`.

However, when invoked like this, `item` is typed as a string:

```
useStrings(["a", "b", "c"], (item) => {});
//                           ^^^^ string
```

The following example gives the desired result, but is of course not a desirable solution:

```
useStrings(["a", "b", "c"] as ("a" | "b" | "c")[], (item) => {});
//                                                  ^^^^ "a" | "b" | "c"
```

How to get `item` inferred as a union without resorting to hacky assertions  such as in the last example?

Answer (score 4):

I don't use infers and my solutions work. Try it yourself!

```
declare function useStrings<T extends string>(
    arr: T[],
    fn: (item: T) => void
): void;
```

[image: Probably don't use infer]

Comment: Damn, mind blown. In trying to apply newly acquired knowledge, I overlooked this much simpler solution. Not sure which answer to accept now.

Comment: It's up to you but he has more than 1k answers and I only 6.

Answer (score 3):

`expr as const` will lower it down into the narrowest possible tuple type, so you should use that and extend your function to work with readonly arrays:

```js
declare function useStrings<T extends readonly string[]>(
  arr: T,
  fn: (item: T extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : never) => void
): void;

useStrings(["a", "b", "c"] as const, (item) => {});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX2QGcQBlDGLVAc0IB4AVeEADwxFWEPjimDwgCe8QuUpUA2gF0AfAAoAUPHiwYALnj0ANIqSp1srGwC26xizYcuPPqkHwDqRCBjwAqgEop8APxv461BAAN2d3eABeaXggnCxgeXd1GLiAbnl5IlJRakJZcQAiKHzNeHyAI2LSsHzJZS4wPBESg2MwyPgAbwBfdxSgA)